# Filemanager in python with wildcard

Tags: python-3.x, path, wildcard, glob

I'm making a script to scan a network folder and copy the files (PDF's) in it to another network folder.
The pdf names start with a number, and this number is also in the name of the destination

Here is my code:

```
import os, shutil, glob
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join files = [f for f in listdir(os.path.join('\\\\fatboy.leleu.be','iedereen','Glenn','Insite')) if isfile(join('\\\\fatboy.leleu.be','iedereen','Glenn','Insite', f))]
dst = glob.glob(os.path.join('\\\\fatboy.leleu.be','iedereen','Glenn','Workflow','2125967_*','PDF Druk'))
for x in files:
    #orderNumber = (x[:7]) <-- get's the 7 numbers
    #client = glob.glob('orderNumber_*') <-- this returns an empty list but should return me the number + name of the client

    path = os.path.join('\\\\fatboy.leleu.be','iedereen','Glenn','Insite', '')
    moveto = os.path.join('\\\\fatboy.leleu.be','iedereen','Glenn','Workflow','2125967_klant_1','PDF Druk')
    files = os.listdir(path)
    files.sort()
    for f in files:
        src = path+f
        dst = moveto
        shutil.move(src,dst)
        print('Succesfully moved', f, 'to', moveto)
```

I'm trying to make the name after the number a wildcard, but glob.glob returns a list and gives an error with path.join

Has anyone some tips for me?